# Setting up Spark Thrift Server on AWS EMR for making JBDC/ODBC connection

Tags: amazon-emr

how to set up the Spark Thrift Server on EMR? I am trying to make a JDBC/ODBC connection to EMR using Spark Thrift Server. For e.g.

beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://10.253.3.5:10015

We execute the following to restart the Hive-Server2 -

sudo stop hive-server2
sudo stop hive-hcatalog-server
sudo start hive-hcatalog-server
sudo start hive-server2

Not sure what are the services to restart Spark Thrift Server on AWS EMR and how to set up the User Id and Password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to start the Spark thrift Server by executing the following on EMR-

sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master yarn-client

The Default port is 10001

Test Connection as below -
/usr/lib/spark/bin/beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://x.x.x.x:10001/default' -e "show databases;"

Spark JDBC Driver can be used to connect to the Thrift Server from any application

Comment: The Spark Thrift Server will take a while to start accepting connections, so if the above beeline commands give your an error and the service is still running, just wait a little and try again.